# Hibernate reverse-engineer database schema from source code

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm currently working on a project that requires determining the database schema based on Java source code. As part of the project, I intend to do this for codebases that employ JPA v2, but for now am focusing on the Hibernate implementation.

To make this more concrete, suppose I am supplied with a folder or JAR of (uncompiled) java files. From this, I would like to determine what tables (and corresponding columns) would be created if this code would be compiled and run (e.g., with a hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = 'create' parameter in the persistence.xml file for the Hibernate implementation), together with the classes and collections (i.e., relationships) that served as a basis for the creation of these tables. This second aspect is key to the scenario, as I want to use this class-table/collection-table mapping later on.

**Example**
Consider the following class definition that is provided as source code:

```
@Entity
public class Animal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> callingNames;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Food> favoriteFoods;
}
```

What I want to deduct from this (and auxiliary classes) is a mapping similar to this:

```
{'Animal.class': 'Animal', 'Food.class': ...},  {'Animal.favoriteFoods':{table:'Animal_Food', sourceColumn:'Animal_id', targetColumn:...}, ...}
```

(Because by default, Hibernate generates a join table with a name of the form *OwnerTableName_TargetTableName* for many-to-many relationships)

In order to achieve this, I've looked at various tools, such as hbm2ddl which can be used to export the database creation scripts and liquibase which supports some sort of source control for databases. However, I do not see a way in which these tools can be used to achieve such a mapping. The [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) class also looks interesting, but seems to only build up the mappings from classes in the classpath (i.e., compiled) or XML-configuration files. I would like to avoid having to compile the source code as the input could involve large and fragmented projects. Moreover, I want to avoid requiring any *.hbm.xml files as an input for this, in order not to impose too much configuration requirements onto the users of my system.

TL;DR So it basically comes down to the following question: is there a way that I can determine the class-table/relationship-table database mapping from source code for Hibernate? I do not want to resort to compiling the source code to find out, and would like both the database schema and the classes/collections that caused their creation from this.

Any indication and/or tools to do this with other implementations is welcome as well, if this would cause a considerable difference in the mapping.

Thanks in advance!